# Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy with spring-web.jar present

Tags: java, xml, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I am getting ClassNotFoundException on org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy when tomcat starts, I have included spring-web.jar, Which has the class org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.

The complete message from tomcat is-->

```
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_1\bin;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_45\bin;C:\Users\A\Programmer\eclipse-jee-kepler-SR1-win32\eclipse;;.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:OnlineCrimeReport' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2Starter' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:TutorialFinder' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AngularPractice1' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:AnnonymousCart' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SpringApp' did not find a matching property.
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 718 ms
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.12
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
SEVERE: Exception starting filter SpringApp
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1676)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1521)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:397)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:252)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.setFilterDef(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:372)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4562)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext$2.call(StandardContext.java:5235)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error filterStart
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/SpringApp] startup failed due to previous errors
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-default.xml]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Unable to locate configuration files of the name struts-plugin.xml, skipping
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts-plugin.xml]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider info
INFO: Parsing configuration file [struts.xml]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.FileManagerFactory)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.XWorkConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.CollectionConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.ArrayConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.DateConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.NumberConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.impl.StringConverter)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionPropertiesProcessor)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionFileProcessor)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ConversionAnnotationProcessor)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterCreator)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.TypeConverterHolder)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.TextProvider)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.LocaleProvider)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionProxyFactory)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.conversion.ObjectTypeDeterminer)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.mapper.ActionMapper)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (jakarta) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequest)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.freemarker.FreemarkerManager)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.components.UrlRenderer)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ActionValidatorManager)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.ValueStackFactory)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionProvider)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.reflection.ReflectionContextFactory)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.PatternMatcher)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StaticContentLoader)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.UnknownHandlerManager)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (org.apache.struts2.views.util.UrlHelper)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.struts2.config.BeanSelectionProvider info
INFO: Choosing bean (struts) for (com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.TextParser)
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocolHandler start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
????? ??, ???? ?:??:?? ??????? org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 4181 ms
```

**web.xml and spring.xml**

**Web.xml**

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>SpringApp</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
  </filter>
  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SpringApp</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </filter-mapping>
```

**spring.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

       <bean name="/home.jsp" class="spring.web.AppController"/>
</beans>
```

All the other files used in application are fine i have checked them in other non spring based applications and spring files in non-web based applications.

Comment: Where have you included the jar?

Comment: check your jar location again

Comment: i have included all required jar's in build path of eclipse and my project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you configured your user library with the deployment assembly.  It should be configured with the WEB-INF. If you would not do so then your eclipse wouldn't know that your class and user library ever.

Comment: it worked, i also got that, only configuring for the Build path is not enough, deployment assembly should also be configured. or use maven.